# WebAPI request authentication in MessageHandler or use authentication filter? What would be the pros and Cons?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My webAPI is trying to authenticate a request that is coming in, I wanted to know if it is a good or bad idea to perform this authentication in MessageHandler or use the authentication filter? What would be pros and cons of using both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the two modes of operation - Authentication MessageHandler or AuthorizationFilter - there's not a tremendous difference in implementation.the filter is more compact and easier to follow what's going on simply because everything is in one place. For most typical custom login scenarios that are tied to business logic, that'll be totally sufficient. The advantage of a message handler is that it's globally applied and is part of the WebAPI pipeline so if several components need to take advantage of BasicAuthentication with different Authorization that would work. But then again you can do that with a filter as well, especially since a MessageHandler still requires a filter for it's authorization.

for more detail refer below links, hope it will be helpful:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/30/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-MessageHandler